# Dynamic text in divs - how to get both to work on same page?

Tags: javascript

I have two DIV tags (and maybe more) with dynamic text.  I need them to cycle in a loop.  I got it working with one DIV tag.  but when I apply the same script to a second DIV tag, only one works.

How do I get both to work at the same time on the same page?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var text = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
 i = 0,
 $div = $('#DIV1');

 setInterval(function ()
 {
 $div.fadeOut(function ()
 {
    $div.text(text[i++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
});
}, 1000);
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var text = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
 i = 0,
 $div = $('#DIV2');

 setInterval(function ()
 {
 $div.fadeOut(function ()
 {
    $div.text(text[i++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
});
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seperate Script tags share the same variables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    var i1 = 0,

    var text2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    var i2 = 0,
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        setInterval(function (){
                $("#DIV1").fadeOut(function ()
            {
                $("#DIV1").text(text[i1++ % text1.length]).fadeIn();
            });
        }, 1000);

        setInterval(function (){
            $("#DIV2").fadeOut(function ()
            {
                $("#DIV2").text(text[i2++ % text2.length]).fadeIn();
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you separate your code in multiple `<script>` tags, it's always the same global scope for all tags (as if all the code was in the same tag). So  `$div` from tag2 will override `$div` from tag1 and the effect will be applied to only one `div`.

You can combine both:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var text = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
   i = 0,
   $divs = $('#DIV1, #DIV2');

   setInterval(function ()
   {
       $divs.fadeOut(function (){
                        $(this).text(text[i++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
                    });
   }, 1000);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the script blocks and script files in a single page share their global variables — the variables from the second block overwrite those from the first.

As a quick fix, you could either change the variable names or [enclose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) the variables within functions, making sure that you declare each variable with the `var` keyword (so that it is not still global):

```
<script>
$(function() {  // wait until the page is ready - $( is short for $(document).ready(

var text = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var i = 0, $div = $('#DIV1');

 setInterval(function ()
 {
 $div.fadeOut(function ()
 {
    $div.text(text[i++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
});
}, 1000);

});
</script>
```

Really, you should take this resulting function, give it a name, and make `text` and `$div` parameters:

```
<script>
function doInterestingFadeEffect(text, $div) {

var i = 0;

 setInterval(function ()
 {
 $div.fadeOut(function ()
 {
    $div.text(text[i++ % text.length]).fadeIn();
});
}, 1000);

}
</script>
```

Then call the function as `doInterestingFadeEffect(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], $('#DIV1'))` for each element of the page you want to affect. It should be possible to do this more nicely using jQuery methods such as [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each) — you should read through the jQuery documentation, which will help you with the details.

However, most important is to know JavaScript itself (rather than focus specifically on jQuery, one of the many available JS libraries) — [read a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/good-javascript-books) if you have to and learn the programming language.